# Prove that a polyhedron in the $\mathcal{H}$-representation is bounded

Tags: geometry, linear-programming, polyhedra, polytopes, discrete-geometry

Given a polyhedron $P$ specified by a set of linear constraints $P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid Ax \le b \}$, what are the conditions on the matrix $A$ such that $P$ is bounded?

I have the following intuition but lack the proof: Rewrite (WLOG I believe) $P=\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \langle \alpha_i,x\rangle \le 1,i=1,2,\ldots,m \ge n+1\}$, then $P$ is bounded iff the cone formed by the vectors $\alpha_i$ equals $\mathbb{R}^n$. (Here $(\alpha_i)_j = A_{ij}/b_i$ .)

Comment: Do you assume x>0?

Comment: No, not necessarily so, although I guess this additional constraint is also of the form $Ax \le b$ and therefore implicitly included.

Comment: @fantasie $x\geqslant0$, not $x>0$. The nonstrict inequality is important!

Answer (score 2):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3458311/269050) a non-empty polyhedron ${\cal P}$ is unbounded if, and only if, for every $z\in\cal P$ there exists a ray with origin in $z$ included in $\cal P$.

If --in addition-- we express ${\cal P}  = \{x\mid Ax \preceq b\}$, we obtain that the existence of such a ray is equivalent to the existence of $v\ne0$ such that $Av\preceq0$.

Comment: This neatly ties into my hypothesis: If the cone $C$ defined by the set $\{\alpha_i\}$ is not equal to $\mathbb{R}^n$, then there is a hyperplane such that $H \cap C =0$. The "outward" normal vector $n$ to this hyperplane has the property $\langle n,\alpha_i \rangle \le 0$, i.e. is the $v$ in your proof.

Comment: @BeMuSeD In you hypothesis, which is the link (if any) between $A$ and the $\alpha_i$? Could you please clarify?

Comment: The $\alpha_i$ are just the rows of $A$, i.e. $A_{i,j}=\alpha_i^j$.